# Boolean value fr checkbox input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have a form with checkboxes like this

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="check_bool" type="checkbox" name="best" <?php if($destination_record[0]->destination_best){echo "checked ='checked'";}?>>
<input type="submit" id="form_submit" value="Update" name="btnUpdate">
```

Now I am converting the values for the check boxes with the following code that is called on form sumission

```
$('#form_submit').click(function() {

    $( ".check_bool" ).each(function() {
        if( $(this ).attr( 'type' ) === 'checkbox' ) {
        if($(this).is( ':checked' )){
            $(this).val('1');
        }else{
            $(this).val('0');
        }

        alert($(this).val());
        }
    })
})
```

But after that I can change all 0 values on checkboxes to 1 but not any 1 value to 0. The alert value is giving 1 or zero accordingly. But when it is 0 I am getting no element in the post array for the checkbox.

Comment: An unchecked checkbox isn't posted. server-side, if you get something you can be sure this was checked, as long as the user didn't interfere and forged a request of course...

Comment: Thank you. I should have known it. I am planning to get the value and store it in some hidden field as my controller accepts many other forms of different kinds here.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are two errors in your php

   - no " after the action in the first row
   - the first input element is not closed

```html
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="check_bool" type="checkbox" name="best" <?php if($destination_record[0]->destination_best){echo "checked ='checked'";}?>>
<input type="submit" id="form_submit" value="Update" name="btnUpdate">
```

2. You have to somehow remove the attribute ,checked='checked', to make the 1 back to 0 again

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for my mistake. The first one was a flaw when I tried to delete the remaining unnecessary design related classes. My original code is actually free from these errors. And still its not working. Can I edit those in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I have just modified my code to have a different hidden field for every checkbox input.

html:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
            <input class="check_bool" type="checkbox" <?php if($destination_record[0]->destination_best){echo "checked ='checked'";}?>/>
            <input type="hidden" name="best" class="check_val" />
</div>
```

Then js :

```
$('#form_submit').click(function() {
    $( ".check_bool" ).each(function() {
        if( $(this ).attr( 'type' ) === 'checkbox' ) {
          if($(this).is( ':checked' )){
            $(this).closest("div").find(".check_val").val('1');
          }else{
            $(this).closest("div").find(".check_val").val('0');
          }

        }
    })
})
```

And its working now.